# Add permissions to Facebook page access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get publish_actions permissions added to one of my page's access tokens. How do I go about doing that? I know you can request certain permissions when you register a new app on a **personal** account -- but I don't understand how to add permissions to an existing **Page** access token.

Comment: You add it to the personal account. And then you do /me/accounts to get page tokens with that permission

Comment: So the first step is to register an app under a personal account?

Comment: Only users can own apps